# ('serviceWorker' in navigator) not returning 'true' when read from file, true otherwise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, coffeescript, service-worker

I have successfully built a Service Worker that controls a few pages in my Rails app (not easy). I've tested it and everything's working in the latest version of Google Chrome. However, if I try and add a conditional to the Service Worker registration script like so:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) #<-- this is what I'm talking about
  #registration stuff
else
  #Your browser does not support service workers
```

The conditional `('serviceWorker' in navigator)` always returns `false` and the Service Worker registration script does not run. If I remove the conditional, everything works. If I type the conditional directly into Chrome's console, it returns `true`.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? My understanding is that `if ('serviceWorker' in navigator)` is the standard check to test a browser's compatibility with Service Workers. The registration script is being served up in its own file by my Rails application in development mode (and again, if I remove the conditional everything works).

Any ideas / avenues to explore are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue: I am using coffeescript instead of javascript (which is standard in Rails). Apparently `in` in coffeescript is very different than `in` in javascript. In coffeescript the correct line is:

```
if 'serviceWorker' of navigator
```

Comment: CoffeeScript's `of` is for looking at object properties (i.e. JavaScript's `in`), CoffeeScript's `in` is for looking at arrays. You'll see the same terminology used in loops: `for e in array` versus `for k, v of object`. The "loop over an array's content" version of `in` is probably the original of the `in` operator in CoffeeScript.

Comment: there is also `if 'serviceWorker' not of navigator` for the inverse